# How I can compress and decompress directory using apache commons compress library in Java?

Tags: java, compression, apache-commons

I want to compress directory and decompress it using apache commons compress library, so

How I can do this?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zip the directory, here is the way to go

```
public static void createZip(String directoryPath, String zipPath) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bOut = null;
        ZipArchiveOutputStream tOut = null;

        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(zipPath));
            bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
            tOut = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(bOut);
            addFileToZip(tOut, directoryPath, "");
        } finally {
            tOut.finish();
            tOut.close();
            bOut.close();
            fOut.close();
        }

 }
```